# Wondering why the size of my char is 4 bits?

Tags: c, char

I am wondering why the size of my char is 4 bit? Shouldn't it be 8 bits by todays standards?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main(){
printf("%zu\n", sizeof(CHAR_BIT));
return 0;
}
```

I am using a 2015 built Laptop i guess with a x64 processor.

Program Output:

```
4
```

Comment: It's not 4 bits.  `CHAR_BIT` is an integer, and `sizeof(int)` is 4 because your integers are 4 bytes.

Comment: But you really need to post some code: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: You probably wanted `printf("%d\n", CHAR_BIT)`.

Comment: Please do not post code and text output as images - [reasoning](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question). Copy it as formatted text into the question.

Comment: Note that `printf("%zu\n", sizeof('a'));` would also output `4`.

Comment: `sizeof` gives you the size of something as abstract bytes.  `CHAR_BIT` tells you how many bits there are in an abstract byte (usually 8, of course).  So `CHAR_BIT` is, usually, something you *multiply by* to get a size in bits.  For example, `sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT` gives you the number of bits in an `int` on your platform.  But saying `sizeof(CHAR_BIT)` isn't very useful or meaningful.

Comment: Note, very few things in C are measured in bits. It's almost always the smallest addressable unit, which is a byte.

Comment: Thanks to everyone. Now i understand a) my mistake and b) what CHAR_BIT actually does. 
I probably misunderstood the book im currently reading (may be because english isn't my first language):)

Comment: Re "*what CHAR_BIT actually does*", Your problem had nothing to do with that it does (which is the size of a byte/`char` in bits).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CHAR_BIT` is something like

```c
#define CHAR_BIT 8
```

As such, you are printing the size of an `int`, which is 4 bytes for you.

I think you wanted

```c
printf( "%d\n", CHAR_BIT );
```